# Display data from a table using Django

Tags: python, django

Can someone please give me a small piece of code where we display data from a table and point me to code that goes into `views.py` and `templates/index.html` to display the table of contents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Read the Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). It shows, in 4 parts, the basics of this framework.

As for your question, a very quick example.

In views.py:

```
def display(request):
  return render_to_response('template.tmpl', {'obj': models.Book.objects.all()})
```

In models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
  publication_year = models.IntegerField()
```

In template.tmpl:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>author</th>
  <th>title</th>
  <th>publication year</th>
</tr>
{% for b in obj %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ b.author }}</td>
  <td>{{ b.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ b.publication_year }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank u very much............U were a lot of help :)

Comment: `render_to_response` should be `render` in django1.6.11 at least.