# Django cannot display model data with dynamic fields

Tags: python, django, model, html-table, field

My Directories app has a predefined variety of different models each of which needs to be selected and returned with its corresponding objects. As a result, since my models are plenty and the user needs to select each one separately I made a dynamic form that passes the model table name `m_tb_name` which is retrieved by my views.py and returns the appropriate model as shown here:

```
*views.py*
def dlist(request):

#get the model table name from the form
m_tb_name= request.POST['model_classes_field']
    #retrieve the model using the table name
model_class = get_model('Directories', m_tb_name)
    # return all model data
model_list = model_class.objects.all() 
# how the data will be handled in list.html template
    #get fields and their names
fields = get_model_fields(model_class)
field_names = model_class._meta.get_all_field_names()
print 'You searched for: %r' % m_tb_name
return render(request, 'Directories/list.html', {'m_tb_name':m_tb_name, 'model_class':model_class, 'model_list':model_list, 'fields':fields, 'field_names':field_names})
```

And since I got the model, its fields and its objects.all() initialized I try to populate a table with the model's data. However, in my template I have this:

```
*list.html*
<table>

    <tr>
    {% for f in fields %}
        <th>{{ f.verbose_name }}</th>           
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    {% for f in fields %}
        {% for mod in model_list %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{mod.f }}</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And although I was expecting some data in my mod.f (specifically I was expecting the data for each particular field of the model) the output is empty, nothing is returned. Any ideas of why this is happening would be helpful.

The idea was to do something like the anwser [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865479/display-from-a-table-using-django) but with dynamic fields not hard coded ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models don't have an `f` attribute, which is how your template variable is being parsed. If you want to do a dynamic lookup on `mod` with the *value* of `f`, you will need to write a simple template filter.

Comment: sry I forgot a line there (first question ever posted!). I reedited my template since `f` was not defined previously. `f` is a model's field name, so I actually want something like `{{ mod.field_name }}`, similar to the answer in the link I posted at the end

Comment: Well, that doesn't change the answer at all. You still need a template filter to resolve `f` dynamically.